# How to get the instance value of a field in a ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm where on first displaying the form, I want to disable one field based on the value of another:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   field_1 = forms.BooleanField(default=False)
   field_2 = forms.CharField(default='mytext', required=True)
```

I.e. if `field_1` is `False`, then `field_2` will have widget attr `disabled`.

I know I can set the `disabled` attr on `__init__` but how do I look up the value of `field_1`? E.g:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   field_1 = forms.BooleanField(default=False)
   field_2 = forms.CharField(default='mytext', required=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    // If field_1 is False then:
       self.fields['field_2'].disabled = True
```

I can get the initial value of `field_1` with `self.fields['field_2'].initial` but I want the actual value of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

After you have called the constructor for the parent class of your form, you can have access to the *instance* attribute which is the instance of the model you want to update, or a new instance of the model you want to create.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields['field_2'].disabled = not self.instance.field_1
```